# Defining range CHECKs on INTERVAL columns (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, intervals, check-constraints

I am currently designing a database that has to deal with a lot of temporal data. Consequently, there are quite a few columns which ought to hold *time interval*-like values. The important thing is that every one of these values has to fit into a fixed set of numerical ranges. Thus, creating database-level constraints to enforce these checks would make a lot of sense (and also provide some useful failsafes).

At first I considered using the `BIGINT` datatype & storing the intervals as UNIX timestamps. This would allow me to write a few simple CHECK constraints and just be done with it. However, investigating the PostgreSQL-specific `INTERVAL` datatype seemed to uncover some really helpful features. Furthermore, using it would probably make more sense in terms of my design's semantics.

The biggest problem I've come a across after switching to `INTERVAL`, though, is that I can't seem to find a nice and uniform way to define the CHECK constraints mentioned earlier.

Here's a rough example of what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE TABLE PURCHASE(
PURCHASE_ID             SERIAL,
PURCHASE_STATE_TYPE_ID  SMALLINT        NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_ID             INTEGER         NOT NULL,
...
COOLINGOFF_PERIOD       INTERVAL(3)     NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK_PURCHASE PRIMARY KEY(PURCHASE_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_PURCHASE_PURCHASE_STATE_TYPE_ID FOREIGN KEY(PURCHASE_STATE_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES PURCHASE_STATE_TYPE(PURCHASE_STATE_TYPE_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
...
CONSTRAINT CHK_PURCHASE_COOLINGOFF_PERIOD_IN_RANGE CHECK((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL COOLINGOFF_PERIOD)) BETWEEN 0 AND 315400000)
...
);
```

In this case, we have the `CHK_PURCHASE_COOLINGOFF_PERIOD_IN_RANGE` CHECK constraint, which enforces the `COOLINGOFF_PERIOD` of each `PURCHASE` to fall between 0 and 10 years.

Unfortunately though, the above DDL statement fails with a syntax error: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "COOLINGOFF_PERIOD".`

Am I missing something here? Is there a nice and clean (*i.e* declarative) way to do this or should I go back to using `BIGINT` instead?

Comment: What's wrong with `between '0'::interval and '10 years'::interval`?

Comment: As @Daniel wrote, use BETWEEN  operator, take a look at this working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/521a2

Comment: @DanielVérité, @kordirko Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for :). To tell the truth, I haven't used the `INTERVAL` type all that much before so I was having a bit of a brain fart regarding these constraints. 

The bit I was suprised about is that you can use the 'years' keyword in definition just like that! I tried all kinds of combinations beforehand and curiously couldn't get them to work.

Now, if one of you could post your comment as a full answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the syntax error in the check constraint is about this part:

```
EPOCH FROM INTERVAL COOLINGOFF_PERIOD
```

which is not accepted because in this context `INTERVAL` is meant to be followed by a literal, as in `INTERVAL '10 days'`

Anyway as suggested in the comments, the translation from `EPOCH` is not even needed, it's easier to write:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
 ...
 COOLINGOFF_PERIOD       INTERVAL(3)     NOT NULL
    CHECK (COOLINGOFF_PERIOD between '0'::interval and '10 years'::interval)
 ...
);
```

See [Interval Input](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) in the doc for all the details and syntax variants.